# Tomcat is not running while Confluence starts

Tags: centos, confluence

CentOS 6.8 64-bit
Atlassian Confluence 5.5.6

Hi. My config is (by default):

```
<Server port="8000" shutdown="SHUTDOWN" debug="0">
<Service name="Tomcat-Standalone">
<Connector port="8090" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"
```

The ports are free

```
conf # netstat -na|grep 8000
conf # netstat -na|grep 8090
```

Trying to start

```
./start-confluence.sh
To run Confluence in the foreground, start the server with start-confluence.sh -fg
executing using dedicated user: confluence
If you encounter issues starting up Confluence Standalone, please see the Installation guide at http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Confluence+Installation+Guide
Server startup logs are located in /opt/atlassian/confluence/logs/catalina.out
Using CATALINA_BASE: /opt/atlassian/confluence
Using CATALINA_HOME: /opt/atlassian/confluence
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/atlassian/confluence/temp
Using JRE_HOME: /opt/atlassian/confluence/jre/
Using CLASSPATH: /opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_PID: /opt/atlassian/confluence/work/catalina.pid
```

Checking the ports again:

```
netstat -na|grep 8000
netstat -na|grep 8090
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:8090 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
```

8090 is listened, but 8000 is not

If I will restart Confluence, there is message after:

```
Mar 02, 2017 1:43:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Could not contact localhost:8000. Tomcat may not be running.
```

Have some warnings in catalina.out, but no errors

```
Mar 02, 2017 1:48:06 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server} Setting property 'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property.
Mar 02, 2017 1:48:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetAllPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetAllPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Connector} Setting property 'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property.
Mar 02, 2017 1:48:06 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine} Setting property 'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property.
Mar 02, 2017 1:48:06 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host} Setting property 'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property.
Mar 02, 2017 1:48:06 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property.
Mar 02, 2017 1:48:07 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8090"]
Mar 02, 2017 1:48:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 822 ms
Mar 02, 2017 1:48:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat-Standalone
Mar 02, 2017 1:48:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
```

Comment: problem with tomcat, can be because of two issue, version mismatch or java. You can also start tomcat with bootstrap.jar.

Comment: @anand Thanks for reply. Tried already start tomcat manually. Received exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory`

Comment: check java version and java_home. 
Also can see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955442/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-juli-logging-logfactory